# The why and how of Chag Ha'Ahava

Tags: sources-mekorot, history, commentaries, chagim-holidays, parties-celebrations

What's the story/history/reason behind calling the 15th of the month Av 'Chag Ha'Ahava' ?

And why, and how was or is this 'Chag Ha'Ahava' celebrated?

Comment: http://www.aish.com/jl/hol/o/48955491.html

Comment: You're prob talking about [this](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Taanit.4.8?with=all&lang=bi) mishna and expanded [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Taanit.31a?lang=bi) in Talmud, but what's the earliest source you've seen referring to it as "chag ha'ahavh"?

Answer (score 2):

Extracted from [here](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/717167/jewish/7-Joyous-Events-That-Happened-on-the-15th-of-Av.htm)

> There were seven joyous events that happened on the 15th of Av
>
> 1. The dancing maidens of Jerusalem
>
> Said Rabbi Shimon ben Gamliel: There were no greater festivals for
>   Israel than the 15th of Av and Yom Kippur.On these days the daughters
>   of Jerusalem would go out... and dance in the vineyards. And what
>   would they say? "Young man, raise your eyes and see which you select
>   for yourself..." (Talmud, Taanit 26b)
>
> 2. The dying of the generation of the Exodus ceased.
>
> After the incident of the spies, G‑d decreed that that entire
>   generation would die out in the desert, and that their children would
>   enter the land in their stead (as recounted in Numbers 13 and 14).
>   After 40 years of wandering through the wilderness, the dying finally
>   ended, and a new generation of Jews stood ready to enter the Holy
>   Land. It was the 15th of Av of the year 2487 from creation (1274 BCE).
>
> 3. The tribes of Israel were permitted to intermarry.
>
> In order to ensure the orderly division of the Holy Land between the
>   twelve tribes of Israel, restrictions had been placed on marriages
>   between members of two different tribes. This ordinance was binding on
>   the generation that conquered and settled the Holy Land; when the
>   restriction was lifted, on the 15th of Av, the event was considered a
>   cause for celebration and festivity.
>
> 4. The tribe of Benjamin was permitted to re-enter the community.
>
> On this date the tribe of Benjamin, which had been excommunicated for
>   its behavior in the incident of the “Concubine at Giv’ah,” was
>   readmitted into the community of Israel (as related in Judges 19–21).
>
> 5. Hoshea ben Elah opened the roads to Jerusalem.
>
> Upon the division of the Holy Land into two kingdoms following the
>   death of King Solomon, Jeroboam ben Nebat, ruler of the breakaway
>   northern kingdom of Israel, set up roadblocks to prevent his citizens
>   from making the thrice-yearly pilgrimage to the Holy Temple in
>   Jerusalem, capital of the southern kingdom of Judah. These were
>   finally removed more than 200 years later by Hoshea ben Elah, the last
>   king of the northern kingdom, on Av 15, 3187 (574 BCE).
>
> 6. The dead of Betar were allowed to be buried.
>
> The fortress of Betar was the last holdout of the Bar Kochba
>   rebellion. When Betar fell, on Av 9, 3893 (133 CE), Bar Kochba and
>   many thousands of Jews were killed; the Romans massacred the survivors
>   of the battle with great cruelty, and would not even allow the Jews to
>   bury their dead. When the dead of Betar were finally brought to burial
>   on Av 15, 3908 (148 CE), an additional blessing (“Hatov Vehameitiv”)
>   was added to the Grace After Meals in commemoration.
>
> 7. “The day of the breaking of the ax.”
>
> When the Holy Temple stood in Jerusalem, the annual cutting of
>   firewood for the altar was concluded on the 15th of Av. The event was
>   celebrated with feasting and rejoicing (as is the custom upon the
>   conclusion of a holy endeavor), and included a ceremonial breaking of
>   the axes, which gave the day its name.

Because of numbers 1, 3 and 4 above, the article [here](https://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/celebrating-romantic-love/) says that

> Tu B’Av is a great day for weddings, commitment ceremonies, renewal of
>   vows, or proposing. It is a day for enhancing current relationships or
>   defining anew what you are looking for in a partner. It is a day for
>   romance, explored through singing, dancing, giving flowers, and
>   studying. The rabbis teach that on Tu B’Av one begins to set more time
>   for studying as the High Holidays approach.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tu_B%27Av#cite_note-8) notes that

> “In modern-day Israel, it is celebrated as a holiday of love (Hebrew:
>   חג האהבה‎‎, Hag HaAhava) etc.